# How do I access a standalone Spark cluster in a Docker container from inside a separate Docker container?

Tags: docker, apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-lab, bitnami

**TL;DR** :

- Spark (`bitnami/spark:3.3.1`) container is accessible with `pyspark` and works fine when outside any container.
- Inside a JupyterLab (`jupyter/pyspark-notebook:ubuntu-20.04`) container, I can connect to the master node with `pyspark`.
- But I can't load any data or run any jobs because the executor fails to start.

---

Here's my setup, I've got Spark running from a Bitnami image (`bitnami/spark:3.3.1`) and a JupyterLab notebook image configured for running Spark from Docker Stacks (`jupyter/pyspark-notebook:ubuntu-20.04`).

From outside any container, this works fine:

```
pyspark --master "spark://localhost:7077"
>>> df = spark.read.parquet('/data/test.parquet')
```

From inside a Docker Stacks JupyterLab PySpark container (`jupyter/pyspark-notebook:ubuntu-20.04`), this command hangs forever:

```
pyspark --master "spark://host.docker.internal:7077"
>>> df = spark.read.parquet('/data/test.parquet')
```

With the warning:

```
23/04/15 20:39:42 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
```

From looking at the logs inside the Spark container, it looks like there's an error with the executor, but I can't seem to figure out what it is:

```
spark_1         | 23/04/15 20:43:19 INFO Master: Registering app PySparkShell
spark_1         | 23/04/15 20:43:19 INFO Master: Registered app PySparkShell with ID app-20230415204319-0000
spark_1         | 23/04/15 20:43:19 INFO Master: Launching executor app-20230415204319-0000/0 on worker worker-20230415204256-192.168.192.2-36639
spark-worker_1  | 23/04/15 20:43:19 INFO Worker: Asked to launch executor app-20230415204319-0000/0 for PySparkShell
spark-worker_1  | 23/04/15 20:43:19 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: spark
spark-worker_1  | 23/04/15 20:43:19 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: spark
spark-worker_1  | 23/04/15 20:43:20 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
spark-worker_1  | 23/04/15 20:43:20 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
spark-worker_1  | 23/04/15 20:43:20 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(spark); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(spark); groups with modify permissions: Set()
spark-worker_1  | 23/04/15 20:43:20 INFO ExecutorRunner: Launch command: "/opt/bitnami/java/bin/java" "-cp" "/opt/bitnami/spark/conf/:/opt/bitnami/spark/jars/*" "-Xmx1024M" "-Dspark.driver.port=36945" "-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions" "--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED" "--add-opens=java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED" "--add-ope`pyspark ns=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED" "--add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED" "--add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED" "--add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED" "--add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED" "--add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED" "--add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent.atomic=ALL-UNNAMED" "--add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED" "--add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.cs=ALL-UNNAMED" "--add-opens=java.base/sun.security.action=ALL-UNNAMED" "--add-opens=java.base/sun.util.calendar=ALL-UNNAMED" "--add-opens=java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5=ALL-UNNAMED" "org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend" "--driver-url" "spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@8c274fc5be53:36945" "--executor-id" "0" "--hostname" "192.168.192.2" "--cores" "1" "--app-id" "app-20230415204319-0000" "--worker-url" "spark://Worker@192.168.192.2:36639"
spark-worker_1  | 23/04/15 20:43:23 INFO Worker: Executor app-20230415204319-0000/0 finished with state EXITED message Command exited with code 1 exitStatus 1
spark-worker_1  | 23/04/15 20:43:23 INFO ExternalShuffleBlockResolver: Clean up non-shuffle and non-RDD files associated with the finished executor 0
spark-worker_1  | 23/04/15 20:43:23 INFO ExternalShuffleBlockResolver: Executor is not registered (appId=app-20230415204319-0000, execId=0)
spark_1         | 23/04/15 20:43:23 INFO Master: Removing executor app-20230415204319-0000/0 because it is EXITED
```

(all but the first two lines repeat forever as the executor keeps trying to restart)

---

Solutions I've found like exposing ports `5000-5010`, `20002`, and `6060` on the Spark master node, increasing the memory allocation for workers, and specifying the `spark.driver.host = host.docker.internal or 0.0.0.0` or `spark.driver.bindAddress = 0.0.0.0` or `spark.blockManager.port = 6060` haven't seemed to work.

If anyone has any advice on what I can do to set this up properly I'd greatly appreciate it! Happy to share more details like the docker-compose script or the Spark environment variables.

Comment: Why not run the Spark standalone server (and a Spark worker) in some Docker compose file, as the jupyter stacks repo documents? If your services are in another container already, make a docker network, do not go through the host.docker.internal address

Comment: I had the first step, but not the second  
Now that you mention it, it was kinda silly to not just link the two containers directly. Thanks for your help, feel free to just paste that as an answer and I'll accept it lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on logs, you already have a docker-compose file with both spark (master) and spark-worker.

If you add the jupyter notebook as a new service to that file, all those containers in the file will be able to reach each other without much, if any, extra configuration.

And you can use `setMaster("spark://spark:7077")` while building a SparkSession in code, rather than use `spark-submit` shell action.